# Garbage Collection on an unnamed class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, garbage-collection

How does the Java GC work on a simple situation like this:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new Object());
list.add(new Object());
//do something with objects
list.remove(0);
```

Comment: The first of your objects is then eligible for garbage collection (assuming "do something with objects" doesn't do something which makes it ineligible). That is all.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. In my actual program I think I made it ineligble somewhere else in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: the class `Object` is not an "unnamed class". If at all, one would use this term in the context of [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

GC retains all objects that are alive, i.e. reachable from GC roots. All other objects are discarded. Local variables are (among others) GC roots.

What you are describing is a situation where there is no reference variable pointing directly to your object, like for instance `Object myObj = new Object();`.

However, there is a list containing a reference to your object.

Now, what would happen if the GC were to run?

- Before `list.remove(0);` your object would be marked as alive since it is
  indirectly reachable through the list.
- After `list.remove(0);` (and assuming "do something with objects"
  doesn't involve establishing another reference to your object) your
  object wouldn't be marked as alive by the GC since it is not reachable
  anymore. The memory that was occupied by your object would afterwards be
  marked as free.

Answer (score 1):

Well typically if use use the object in the "do something with objects" that causes them to be retained then they will not be garbage collected despite the `list.remove` call.

Also try and make sure you declare the `list` in the shortest scope possible. That is closest to where it is being used. That would make the list automatically fall out of scope and be GC'd earlier.

Also sometimes you may want to set the object to null after you are done using it. That as well works to get it off scope and eligible for GC.

Comment: In your third paragraph you mention setting the object to null. Do you mean set the list location of the object to null?

Comment: No i mean after you are done working with the object in the list set it to null .